# gdalwarp reproject "Lambert Conformal Conic" to EPSG:4326 and stretch vertically to avoid shape distortion

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am trying to convert "Lambert Conformal Conic" into "map-like" representation (which is EPSG:4326 as far as I understood), so I used

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff /tmp/src.tiff /tmp/dst.tiff
```

And I suppose I'm getting the correct re-projection technically were all latitude's degree length is equal to longitude's degree length; however due to the distortion because of a conversion I noticed that objects are stretched horizontally closer to the pole, if the object's distortion is more of a concern than equality of longitude==latitude, how can I gradually stretch the resulting map vertically to eliminate this distortion?

I've tried `gdal_translate` with vertical transformation, however since the ratio is different near equator and near the pole the final results of applying straight ratio like 1x to 1.2y are not satisfying enough.

Comment: If you use a coordinate system aware viewer the stretch does not matter because the viewer knows how to stretch the image back. It you want that image looks about "good" with standard photo viewers you can create non-rectangular pixels with gdalwarp `-tr xres yres`.

Comment: The worldwide gradual stretch is not possible with EPSG:4326, or maybe one could say that the result would be a new projection. However, there are already alternatives to select from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections. Maybe some of the equal area projections would please you.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Sorry I tried to fix the projection by stretching the result instead of choosing a different projection from the beginning. The following command completely covers all requirements:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -of GTiff /tmp/src.tiff /tmp/dst.tiff
```

The Web Mercator projection was chosen since it "stretches" more vertically being further from the equator and as a result the distortion is unnoticeable from a glance

Comment: @user30184, could you put the link to map projections as an answer? I would be happy to mark it as an answer.